# Debian : SSH port attack continues, cannot change port coz of provider, suggestions?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian

We have a debian server, which is running our Tomcat hosted applications and we have installed `Fail2Ban` on it. Everyday morning I see that a lot of people on the internet try to attack the server.

One time, I took action on it, I disabled root login for ssh, changed default SSH port-number, and only specific user-names were allowed to login. Now, because of that, the softwares provided by our Hosting providers for taking backup and monitoring failed. Also the admins couldn't login. For that I had to revert the changes I had done.

Is there any way for this problem. I would hate for some user to get lucky and compromise the server. These are the ideas I have, how do they sound :

1. Root access only allowed in intranet.
2. Default port only allowed in Intranet.
3. Admin has installed SSH certificates in `authorized_keys`, anyhow that can be useful?

Any other ideas, thank you. :-)

Comment: Do you a firewall in your hosting provider? If so, you can config access to ssh port only to your IP. And if the hosting provider doesn't use internal IPs open it also to the hosting IP range.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139285/limit-max-connections-per-ip-address-and-new-connections-per-second-with-iptable Block new connections if they exceeds rate limit.

Answer (score 2):

- Disable root access completely.
- Disable password access completely, only allow key-based login.
- Continue to use fail2ban

That's about it and will protect you from anyone "getting lucky" with a password guess.

Comment: The password is complicated enough which cannot be guessed. I cannot disable root access as the backup softwares/ Admins access via root. If that was possible, it would have been very easy for me.. :-)

Comment: Your 2nd point seems interesting. I will contact the admin and will be back. THank you. :-)

Comment: Admins **should** use `sudo` anyway. If you claim the password is secure, what do you worry about?

Comment: Because right now users are trying brute-force which they are failing at, I just want to discourage proficient attackers who can perform some advanced attacks, god knows what.

Comment: Just dissable `password auth` then, most of attacks are to `root` user with dummy passwords.

Comment: I would add that you should setup SSH to listen on a 2nd port (just add a second ```Port``` line), then restrict access to 22/tcp to the hosting providers IP ranges with the firewall.  Use the second SSH port for normal access to the box from outside.  The primary purpose of putting SSH on a non-standard port is to cut down on log traffic, but it serves a secondary purpose as speed-bump security to slow down automated attacks.

Comment: @tgharold : Intriguing, currently I disabled passwords as the providers have there keys in authorized_keys, and it is working good as of now. I would like to know how I can limit the providers, backup software at 22?

Comment: @tgharold : I have 2 keys which start with ssh-rsa in authorized_keys, but one key starts with from and an IP address. That also I would need to isolate to 22.

Comment: I would allow the provider's backup software to login at both 22 and the alternate port (you gain nothing by blocking it).  The bigger gain would be to change the IP firewall (iptables or ufw) so that port 22 is only reachable from the provider's IP address ranges instead of being reachable from the entire world.